# Got error 'invalid UTF-8 string at offset 1' from regexp

Tags: regex, database, codeigniter, query-builder

I need help, I have tried to find the solution but until now all I have found is stuff related to regex but I think the problem might be in another place.

I have a project locally (Windows 10 --> Xampp Latest version [Apache & Mysql], I use CodeIgniter as Framework, I developed a function which searches in my database using REGEXP (I use query builder)

It works fine and everything. Here I searched for `saltarín` <-- Note the accent on the letter `i`
[image]

So now that it works I have decided to update the online website but as soon as I was testing the online project I noticed an error jumps when I search something with accented characters or in this case the letter `ñ` which also works locally.

[image]
I checked my database configurations, in `database.php` I have dbcollat set to utf8_spanish_ci and my online database and tables are set to utf8_spanish_ci too, I think this must be a server configuration but I don't have an idea of what it really could be

In case you need it this is the piece of code which uses regexp

```
$this->db->where("lower(secret_colum_name) REGEXP", $this->secret_hehe);
```

Thanks a lot for your time, I really appreciate your help.

**EDIT:**  I forgot to mention I'm using hostinger to host my website

Comment: Please provide the exact binary data (preferably in pairs of hexadecimals) for that value.

Comment: I'm not really sure about what you are asking for, I think you could refer to the string the query looks for, In this case, is "cuñada". If I'm wrong please correct me.

Comment: use `SELECT HEX(...)`, and post what you get for that problematic value

Answer (score 0):

It's me again. It was just as I suspected it was something about the server, After some hours of research I found out that my server didn't have the same extensions and configurations, you can use `php -m` command to find out your local extensions so you can then enable them on your remote server which in my case I had to do by c-panel but your case could be different.

[image]

I also changed my php version in the remote server and I'm not really sure about the next thing but it might have helped.

I had a setter defined in my model which did the next thing

```
$this->my_var = strtolower($my_var);
```

I removed `strtolower` and after all the steps previously mentioned I reloaded my site and now it works

[image]